# Como puedo leer datos numericos de un fichero txt, y pasarlo a vector con python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando crear un vector (vector), y pasarlo a un fichero .txt para almacenarlo, y posteriormente poder recuperarlo como vector2, para poder operar con el con python, pero cuando intento operar con vector 2 me da el siguiente errorpero me da el siguiente error

> TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature
>   matching types dtype('

Os dejo el código:

```
import numpy as np

lista=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
vector=np.array(lista)
print (vector)
lista.append(9)
vector=np.array(lista)
print (vector)
archivo= open('datos.txt','w')

archivo.write('%s'%vector)

archivo=open('datos.txt','r')
dades=archivo.read()


vector2=np.array(dades)

print(vector2)
print(vector2*2)
```

No hay manera de que cuando lea los datos desde txt, lo pueda pasar a vector.

Muchas gracias y espero respuestas. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar [np.savetext](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) para escribir el array en el archivo de texto. Luego, con [np.genfromtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) para leer los datos del archivo. De esa forma tendrías:

```
import numpy as np

lista=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] 
vector=np.array(lista) 
print (vector) 
lista.append(9) 
vector=np.array(lista) 
print (vector) 

np.savetxt("datos.txt", vector, newline=" ", fmt="%d")

vector2 = np.genfromtxt('datos.txt', dtype='int')

print (vector2*2)
```

Salida:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[ 2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

Mientras escribía esta respuesta se ha publicado otra que ya te da la solución, así que en esta me limitaré a explicar un poco por qué no funcionaba tu enfoque original.

Con la línea `archivo.write('%s'%vector)` estás convirtiendo el vector a su representación como cadena, y es esa cadena la que guardas en el fichero.

El fichero por tanto contiene el texto `"[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]"`. Cuando luego lo lees en la variable `dades`, esta variable será una cadena (string), y cuando finalmente intentas convertirla en vector numpy mediante `np.array(dades)` no obtienes el resultado que esperas, ya que a esta función no le estás pasando una lista de números, sino una cadena.

El "array" resultante `vector2` tiene un solo elemento, y no nueve, y ese único elemento es la cadena `"[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]"`. El extraño error que obtienes se debe a que `numpy` no sabe operar con este tipo de datos.

La solución más simple es usar las funciones que `numpy` te da para guardar datos en archivos de texto, como te han respondido en otra respuesta. Por ejemplo `numpy.savetext(vector)` producirá un archivo de texto que contendrá:

```
1.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00
```

el cual puede leerse con `numpy.readtxt()` o con `numpy.genfromtxt()`, que son funciones que puede convertir las cadenas leidas a números y con ellos reconstruir el vector original.